# Dynamically Register Sidebars For Each Top Level Page

Tags: functions, widgets, sidebar

I have a small website that wants a different sidebar for each page containing blocks of text, blocks of images, and blocks of links, etc. What I'm trying to do is register a sidebar for each top level page:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ){
    $topLevel = get_pages(array(
        'sort_column'   => 'post_date',
        'hierarchical'  => 0,
        'parent'        => 0,
        'post_type'     => 'page',
        'post_status'   => 'publish'
    ));

    foreach($topLevel as $page)
    {
        //make alphaunermic
        $sidebarID = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", strtolower($page->post_title));

        //Clean multiple dashes or whitespaces
        $sidebarID = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", strtolower($page->post_title));

        //Convert whitespaces and underscore to dash
        $sidebarID = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", strtolower($page->post_title));

        register_sidebar(array(  
          'name' => $page->post_title,  
          'id'   => $sidebarID, 
          'description'   => '',  
          'before_widget' => '<div id="'.$sidebarID.'" class="widget">'  
          'after_widget'  => '</div>',  
          'before_title'  => '<h2>',  
          'after_title'   => '</h2>'  
        ));
    }
}
```

1) is this possible?

2) is there a better way to go about this?

3) I'm getting a few errors...

Comment: From where are you doing this and when are you doing it (on which hook)?`

Comment: Well I'm doing it at the beginning of function.php - no hook, should I use the `widgets_init` hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code for creating unique sidebar for each parent page

> you can use `$page->post_name`(page slug) or `$page->ID`(page id) as
>   sidebar id

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ){
    /*extract all parent pages */
    $topLevel = get_pages(array(
        'sort_column' => 'post_date',
        'hierarchical' => 0,
        'parent' => 0
    ));

    foreach($topLevel as $page){
        /* register sidebar for each parent page */
        register_sidebar(array(  
          'name' => $page->post_title,  
          'id'   => 'sidebar-'.$page->post_name, 
          'description'   => 'This widget display on page "'.$page->post_title.'"',  
          'before_widget' => '<div id="'.$sidebarID.'" class="widget">',
          'after_widget'  => '</div>',  
          'before_title'  => '<h2>',  
          'after_title'   => '</h2>'  
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrap this code in a function and hook it on `widgets_init` action.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this to display different content on different pages and your sidebars are the same width (well, maybe you can change it by adding a class to the body of each page), a much simpler approach would be to just use Display Widgets and have just one sidebar:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/display-widgets/

It allows you to choose which widgets show up on which page/s.

Comment: While I agree, I'm trying to keep it as vanilla as possible, meaning little to no plugins.

Comment: Oh, ok.  Well, before I found that plugin I used to register the sidebars in the functions and then created a page template for each area of the site that needs to call a different sidebar.  It was a bit more work.