# Dynamic Sidebar Conditional

Tags: sidebar, conditional-content, register-sidebar

**EDIT**

Answer was found here: [is_active_sidebar() Always Returns False](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117546/is-active-sidebar-always-returns-false)

By user: `s_ha_dum`

---

I'm dynamically creating sidebars and registering them for every top level page:

[Dynamically Register Sidebars For Each Top Level Page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107821/dynamically-register-sidebars-for-each-top-level-page)

The problem is, I want to test if a sidebar doesn't exist for that page, to use default:

```
if(is_dynamic_sidebar(get_the_title()))
                    dynamic_sidebar(get_the_title());
                else
                    dynamic_sidebar('Default');
```

I've tried to test

`if(is_dynamic_sidebar(get_the_title()) && dynamic_sidebar(get_the_title())`
but this just repeats the sidebar content twice for some reason. I also tried:

`if(is_dynamic_sidebar(get_the_title()) && is_active_sidebar(get_the_title())`
but this just removes all my sidebars or if I change the `&&` to `||` it will display normally except never uses default. So pretty much on my subpages, it uses no sidebar. Anybody have suggestions on what I can do?

Updated Code thanks to @Ravs

```
if(!is_active_sidebar(get_the_title()))
    dynamic_sidebar(get_the_title());
else 
    dynamic_sidebar('Default');
```

Comment: `is_dynamic_sidebar` has no parameter to pass.check `is_active_sidebar` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_sidebar

Comment: You're completely right, still not going to default though for subpages :/   - so not exactly problem solved. Thanks though!

Comment: I think your edit should be: `if( is_active_sidebar(get_the_title()) )`. Remove the negation (`!`).

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic sidebar code you are using uses the page title of the topmost page to name the sidebar. `get_the_title` finds the title of the page you are on, not the topmost page title. You need a function that tells you the title of the topmost page in a page hierarchy.

```
/**
 * Get the topmost page title.
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107843/dynamic-sidebar-conditional
 */
function wpse_107843_get_top_parent_page_title() {
    global $post;

    $parent_page = get_post( $post->ID );

    // Recurse to top parent.
    while ( $parent_page->post_parent != 0 )
        $parent_page = get_post( $parent_page->post_parent );

    return $parent_page->post_title;
}
```

Comment: While you are right, I am generating each sidebar with the same name as the page title, so if the sidebar with that page title doesn't exist then go to default.

Comment: Yes. I think I misunderstood the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have specific sidebar on parent pages and default sidebar for subpages, your condition may be ( i am assuming your are in wordpress loop )

1. check for page,  parent page or sub page.
2. check sidebar widget area exist for page if current page is parent page

> [`dynamic_sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar#Return_Value) return True, if widget sidebar was found and called. False if not found or
>   not called.

```
    if($post->post_parent == 0 ){ // if page is a parent page
      if(dynamic_sidebar(get_the_title()) && is_active_sidebar(get_the_title()))
         dynamic_sidebar(get_the_title());
      else 
         dynamic_sidebar('Default');
    }
    else{ // if page is a sub page
      dynamic_sidebar('Default');
    }
```